# How to convert simple php array into json data with heads

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress, converters

I am getting post object data in WordPress, and here is my code

```
$pre_items = get_post_meta( $post_object->ID, 'rudr_select2_tags');
```

The print_r provide me this data

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [Apple iPhone 5,Apple iPhone 6] => 1 ) )
```

I have written the below code

```
  $pre_items = get_post_meta( $post_object->ID, 'rudr_select2_tags');
  $new_arr = array();

  foreach($pre_items as $arr){
    $process_array = array();
    $process_array['id'] = $arr;
    $process_array['name'] = $arr;
    array_push($new_arr,$process_array);
   }

   $items = json_encode($new_arr);
```

but this code returns data

```
[{"id":{"Apple iPhone 5,Apple iPhone 6":1},"name":{"Apple iPhone 5,Apple iPhone 6":1}}]
```

But I want data in the below format

```
[{id: Apple iPhone 5, name: "Apple iPhone 5"},
{id: Apple iPhone 6, name: "Apple iPhone 5"}
]
```

Please help how to acheive this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the third paramater to get_post_meta  to toggle return of a single value, and explode the array key to seperate the devices in order to structure the data as per your example.

```
$pre_items = get_post_meta( $post_object->ID, 'rudr_select2_tags', true);
$new_arr = array();

foreach($pre_items as $key => $value ){

    // Split key into array.
    $devices = explode( ',', $key );

    // name is set to first device.
    $name = $devices[0];

    foreach ( $devices as $device ) {
        $process_array = array(
            'id' => $device,
            'name' => $name,
        );
        array_push($new_arr, $process_array);
    }

}

$items = json_encode($new_arr);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works,
Just there is a comma missing in the line 7 before $key